# How to Use TF-IDF and combine it with Information Gain for feature selection in text classification?

Tags: text-classification, information-retrieval, tf-idf, feature-selection, information-gain

i don't know the concept of how to combine TF-IDF result and use it in information gain mathematically .
can someone explain it for me please?

Comment: I think wrong stack-exchange question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sklearn FeatureUnion https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html#sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion and sklearn hstack https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.hstack.html

Comment: thankyou for your answer, can you explain how to do manual calculation for that?